# Post Json Data in the API

Tags: json, post, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, webclient

I'm developing WP8 app and i want to know my post method is correct or not because i'm unable to post my data in the url it produces an exception..

**My Class**

```
public class Register     
    {

        public int id { get; set; }
        public string password_reset_hash { get; set; }
        public string temp_password { get; set; }
        public bool remember_me { get; set; }
        public string activation_hash { get; set; }
        public string ip_address { get; set; }
        public bool status { get; set; }
        public bool activated { get; set; }
        public string permissions { get; set; }
        public DateTime last_login { get; set; }
        public DateTime created_at { get; set; }
        public DateTime updated_at { get; set; }
        public string email { get; set; }
        public string password { get; set; }
        public string conformpassword { get; set; }
        public string username { get; set; }      
    }
```

**my code**

```
 public  void btn_register_click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            string url="myurl";
            Register res=new Register();// my class
            res.email = txt_email.Text;
            res.password = txt_password.Text;
            res.conformpassword = txt_conf_psswrd.Text;
            res.username = txt_username.Text;
            res.created_at = DateTime.Now;
            res.last_login = DateTime.Now;
            res.updated_at = DateTime.Now;
            res.status = true;
            
            json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(res);
            WebClient wc = new WebClient();
            var URI = new Uri(url);  
            wc.Headers["Content-Type"] = "application/json";                
            wc.Headers["ACCEPT"] = "application/json";
            wc.UploadStringCompleted += new UploadStringCompletedEventHandler(wc_UploadStringCompleted);
            wc.UploadStringAsync(URI, "POST", json);             

        }

        private void wc_UploadStringCompleted(object sender, UploadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                MessageBox.Show(e.Result); 
                //e.result fetches you the response against your POST request.         

            }

            catch (Exception exc)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(exc.ToString()); //i'm getting error here..
            }
        }
```

**Error i am getting**

[image]

Comment: "The remote server returned an error: NotFound" It said.

Comment: what to do with that error..? the remote server is active..i had used GET method to get the data from the url..

Comment: It means that, remote server can't find right controller and action for your request. Or maybe controller action for some reason returns NotFound error message.

Comment: how can i fix this problem..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. you should  use HttpClient or RestSharp(http://www.nuget.org/packages/RestSharp/).
2. if api base on .net use jsonp or use web api 2 with EnableCors

Answer (score 1):

You should use *HttpClient* instead. Something along the lines of:

```
var client = new HttpClient();
client.SendAsync(<url>, data);
```

**EDIT**

Do you API exist at "myurl"?

Comment: if u can modify my code r can u suggest any sample methods to complete it..i'm cant able to find a solution for post method..